# C++ Encapsulation and references in constructor

Tags: c++, oop

I'm having a trouble putting together the concept of encapsulation (no one else should change the object data directly) and good performance recommendations when someone pass parameters.

For this code

```
// Code only for illustration, I'm not looking for syntax comments (thanks)
class Person{
private:
    std::string name;
    std::string Id;

public:
    Person(std::string _name, std::vector<double> vec)...
```

I get that the most recommended thing to use is `const` references for parameters (even the compiler warns that). But this let the objects depending on the code that call them?

In the code above, if I pass by reference the `vector`, and the object needs to create a copy of that, or modify,  don't be passing by value the same?. What happen with the object when someone else modify that referenced vector?

Hope this is readable

Comment: What effect would the dependency on the calling code have? Does it have that effect?

Comment: There are several capitalization errors in your code.

Comment: If your member aren't references, then it depends on their type. Standard containers like `std::string` use value semantics and make copies of whatever you initialize them with.

Comment: Unless your class goes out of its way to store a reference or pointer to an argument - which yours doesn't - then your class is unaffected if an object passed by reference changes.    By default, C++ uses value semantics so (among other things) assignment copies the value, rather than reference semantics which you seem to be assuming it does.

Comment: In the case that an object stores a copy for each parameter as class members. The recommendation for the parameters is to have them as const references then? How many memory I save against having the parameters by value? Or it's the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a class

```
class Person{
    std::string name;
public:
    Person(std::string _name){
        //Body of constructor
    }
};
```

then there are *two* strings accessible in the body of the constructor: the member `name` of the instance of `Person` being constructed, and the parameter `_name` of the function. Usually, what the constructor would do would be something like*

```
    Person(std::string _name){
        name = _name;
    }
```

which says "copy that value of `_name` into `name`" - and which has the desired behavior that `name` is an object independent of anything else.

The trouble with this is that if we somewhere else wanted to construct an instance of `Person` and already had a string in mind - for instance we wrote the code

```
std::string namePassed = "Alice";
Person person(namePassed);
```

the compiler would then have to generate code to pass `namePassed` by value - which means that the compiler will *copy* `namePassed` into a new location which will be referenced by `_name` inside the body of the constructor. That means that the whole sequence of events that happens for construction is as follows:

1. `namePassed` is copied to the argument `_name`.
2. The argument `_name` is copied to the member `name`.
3. The argument `_name` is destructed.

What we really wanted to happen is that `namedPassed` would simply be copied** to the member `name` - we don't want to make a temporary copy for no reason!

The solution to this is to pass `_name` by const reference as

```
    Person(std::string const& _name){
        name = _name;
    }
```

because then when we write

```
std::string namePassed = "Alice";
Person person(namePassed);
```

the compiler says that `_name` is a reference (essentially a pointer) to `namePassed` and then copies to `name` from that reference - meaning that the member `name` still ends up with an independent copy, but we avoided the extra copying operation. If we later assigned to `namePassed`, that would be okay because the member `name` is a copy, sharing no state with `namePassed` and the parameter `_name` would have left scope***. The `const&` qualification only applies to the temporary parameter, not to member.

If you wanted to store a member reference, you would have to declare the member as a constant reference, not just the parameter. That would look like this:

```
class Person{
    std::string const& name;
public:
    Person(std;:string const& _name):name(_name){}
};
```

This is a bad idea outside of a few niche situations, since now the reference to the string must be alive as long as the instance of Person is and changes to the referenced string will be reflected in the class - but note that the member being *stored* is marked `const&` not just the parameter.

---

*The code here is not idiomatic since I wanted to emphasize the copy operation. More common is to just write

```
    Person(std::string const& _name):name(_name){}
```

which uses an initializer list. The former code said "default initialize `name` (i.e. initialize an empty string) and then assign a value to it" whereas this code directly invokes the copy constructor for `name` with the given argument.

**There's a bit of complication by the move (rvalue) semantics, but that's somewhat beyond the scope of this answer. It's worth noting that there's a fairly common construction where one passes-by-value then moves:

```
    Person(std::string _name):name(std::move(_name)){}
```

which expresses the idea that we can pass in a value `_name` which is guaranteed to be an independent copy of the string. Then, knowing that it's a copy, we can *move* it into place, which basically means that we steal the memory used by `_name` and give it to `name`, which is far less expensive than copying the whole string and less annoying than writing separate constructors for rvalues and lvalues.

***It's possible to get errors, however, if the value of `namePassed` managed to change *during* the execution of the constructor, but *before* the copy was made, then `name` could be copied from the wrong source. This is mostly an issue that arises when writing multithreaded code.

Comment: Thanks! Quick question, in terms of encapsulation (Conceptually), the only thing that can mess things up is to have pointers as class members  (of any kind) or references to memory who are out of the object scope?. PS. This concepts are so much easy to explain in lenguajes like Java, PHP, or JAVA.

Comment: @CristianRodríguez Encapsulation is a bit more of a broad design concept - a more precise way to understand this is as *value* vs. *reference* semantics: when you assign to a *value*, you create an independent copy that doesn't depend on what later happens to what you copied. When you assign to a *reference* (or pointer), you're doing something more low-level: you're saying that there's a segment of memory somewhere containing a value you'd like to read/write later. If your class's members are all values, the class itself will behave like a value - which is usually what you want.